# Add diretictive validator in component wrapper - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I add a directive validator in a component that wrap an input with ng-model?

**Validator**:

```
angular.module('app').directive('validateInput', validateInput)


function validateInput(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        required: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    }

    function link(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
        //ctrl.$validators....
    }
}
```

**Component usage**:

```
<input-component model="myModel" validate-input></input-component>
```

**Component template**:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model" />
```

Ps.: I summarized to simplify, but I need it in this way

Comment: the validator is for the <input>?

Comment: Yeah, but I need put in component to be dynamic

Comment: you should be able to do `<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model" validate-input />` in your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a directive to encapsulate the input in a template, right?

The problem with inputs inside directives is that you lose some angular directives.

For example: Imagine that now you want to add a ngChange to the same input. you would have to add a scope ngChange inside the wrapper, and then apply it to the input. That happens for every new directive that you want to apply.

The solution? Using transclusion to add the input inside your input wrapper, and simply apply the validate-input, or whatever directive, to it.

**HTML**

```
<input-component> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" validate-input/>
</input-component>
```

**Directive JS**

```
...
return {
     restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
     template: '...<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>...'
}
...
```